# Laravel Eloquent: how to add a column to a query response?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

In other words, lets say i have a query like that:

```
return Location::valid()
    ->with('owners', 'gardeners')
    ->withCount('gardeners')
    ->get();
```

that returns some json :

```
[
 {
   name: 'LocationA',
   nb_gardeners_max: 3,
   owners: [...],
   garderners: [...],
   garderners_count: 2
 }
]
```

in the json response i'd like to add some custom entry like **is_full** and **available_places**:

```
[
 {
   name: 'LocationA',
   nb_gardeners_max: 3,
   owners: [...],
   garderners: [...],
   garderners_count: 2,
   ...
   is_full: false,
   available_places: 1
 }
]
```

I guess it has something to do with raw / join / aggregate... but i really don't understand how to do so. Any help will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

Minhajul answer is really usefull but it's not possible to do a WHERE clause on the appended attribute.

```
Location::where('is_full',true)->get() // NOT WORKING
```

Though it's still possible to do filter() on it, I'd like to use a JOIN for that to perform a single query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do so, you can add attributes that do not have a corresponding column in your database.To do this, all you need to modify your model

```
public function getIsFullAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['name'] == 'value';
}
```

After creating this accessor, you need to add this in your model.

```
 protected $appends = ['is_full'];
```

Hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: on more question, it seems that it's not possible to do a where clause on those attributes.. is there a way?

Comment: $locationData = Location::valid()
    ->with('owners', 'gardeners')
    ->withCount('gardeners')
    ->get();
$finalData = $locationData->filter(function($data)){
    return is_full > 0;
}

I am not saying it's the best way but it should work.

Comment: thanks, i know the filter way but the join method is still a quest :)